# Recreating a non-straightforward Excel 'vlookup'

Tags: excel, vlookup, tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm looking for some thoughts on how you might recreate a 'vlookup' that I currently do in excel.

I have two tables: **Data** contains a list of datetime values; **DateConverter**; contains a list of calendar dates and their associated "network dates."  Imagine for a business - not every day is a workday, so if I want to calculate differences in dates, I'm most interested in the number of work days that elapsed between my two dates.

Here is what the data might look like:

```
Data Table             DateConverter Table
=================      ===================

| Datetime      |      | Calendar date | Netowrk date |
| ------------- |      | ------------- | ------------ |
| 6-1-15 8:00a  |      | 6-1-15        | 1000         |
| 6-2-15 1:00p  |      | 6-2-15        | 1001         |
| 6-3-15 7:00a  |      | 6-3-15        | 1002         |
| 6-10-15 3:00p |      | 6-4-15        | 1003         |
| 6-15-15 1:00p |      | 6-5-15        | 1004         |
| 6-12-15 2:00a |      | 6-8-15        | 1005         | // Skips the weekend
| ...           |      | ...           | ...          |
```

In excel, I can easily map in the network date for each date in the **Datetime** field with a variant of `vlookup`:

```
// Assume that Datetime values are in Column A, Calendar date values in
// Column C, Network date values in Column D - this formula fills Column B
// Headers are in row 1 - first values are in row 2

B2=OFFSET($D$1,COUNTIFS($C:$C,"<"&A2),)
```

The formula counts the dates that are less than the lookup value (using `countifs` because the values in the search array are dates, and the search value is datetime) and returns the associate network date.

Is there a way to do this in Tableau?  Will it require a calculated field or can I do this with some kind of join?

Thanks in advance for the help!  Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: Are your 2 tables hosted on the same database server (or tabs in the same Excel file)? Or are they coming from different sources altogether?

Comment: Currently  - they can be the same file (tabs in the same Excel).  However, in the future - they would be separate files (e.g., one is a SQL db, other in excel).

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are on the same data server, you have the option to use joins, which is usually the most efficient way to combine information from different tables. If the tables are on different servers or platforms, then you can't use a single query to join them.

In either case, you can use Tableau data blending, which is sort of like a client-side join of aggregated results from multiple queries. Its a pretty useful technique, but a little more complex and restricted and also usually less efficient than a server side join.

So if you have the option to have both tables on the same server, start with that. It will be simpler and likely faster.

Note if you are going to use a date as a join key, you probably want to define it is a date and not a datetime.

Comment: Thanks Alex - couple of questions: 1) For joins - I don't have control over datatypes, is there a way to "loosely" join? 2) For blending - I will have some null matches (which I believe forces the whole column null when aggregating), any way to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

@alex-blakemore's response would normally be adequate, but if you can change the schema, you could simply add the network date to the DataTable. The hourly granularity should not cause excessive growth and you don't need to navigate the joining.

Then, instead of counting rows and requiring a sorted table, simply subtract the Network date from each other and add 1.